# Impact of binary code length on performance of CUDA program

Tags: performance, cuda

I wrote a CUDA program that has several subroutines. When I disable subroutine A, the runtime improves by amount a. When I disable subroutine B the runtime improves by amount b. When I disable subroutines A and B the runtime improves by amount c > a + b. Both subroutines are completely independent of each other.

This next part may be a naive approach to analyze this, but here is what I did: I compiled each version of the code and ran *cuobjdump --dump-sass* for each binary. The resulting output was about 1350 lines for the complete binary and around 1100 lines for each binary with one subroutine disabled. If I disabled both subroutines I got 850 lines. It appears that I need 3.1 us per line for the first three and 2.4 us for both subroutines disabled.

Since A and B do not contain anything complicated or use memory more intensively than the rest of the code I do not think that this is caused by commenting out all the time intensive operations and leaving the simple ones active. My guess is that the program code with both A and B disabled still fits in the streaming multiprocessors' instruction caches while the other versions are too large. That might result in global memory accesses so that more program code can be loaded and the latency causes this discrepancy. Unfortunately I could not find any information on the instruction cache size.

Can anyone help me with the interpretation of these results?

Comment: You need to be *very* careful when making this type of analysis. The GPU compiler and assembler have very aggressive "dead code removal" optimisation. If the compiler can determine a code section doesn't contribute to a result which is written to global memory, it will just remove whole sections of code from the kernel.

Comment: Yes, but that shouldn't that have already happened when I run <em>cuobjdump --dump-sass</em>? I am wondering about the drop in runtime and whether that may have anything to do with the length of the binary code.

Comment: The current version of the CUDA profilers do not show Instruction Cache statistics. The Nsight Visual Studio Edition CUDA Profiler does show stall reasons. If the primary stall reason is Fetch then the kernel is likely thrashing the icache or you have a lot of jumps. Further interpretation would require profiling reports and review of the code.

Comment: Did you check the register usage? It could be that having either A or B requires more registers than neither A nor B. A reduced register count might be improving occupancy and so performance.

Comment: The number of blocks per streaming multiprocessor was limited to 8 by shared memory usage and less than 40 registers were used per block. So there was no increase in occupancy there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be several things leading to your results. Some may include:

- Lack of A & B leads to some additional optimization of the remaining code. The resulting code might not be *shorter* but may still execute faster.
- The optimizer found that certain code in A exists also in B (A and B may still be independent). As a result having both A & B slows the program less than having separate A and separate B.
- Having just A or B (or neither) results in better memory access patterns or more cache hits when reading the data in the *remaining* code. (I am talking about data, not program code)
- Lack of A and B may lead to better occupancy, allowing more threads to be run concurrently.

I highly doubt that the instruction cache might be the issue. Even if global memory reads were necessary, it is never "misaligned" as warp always needs only one instruction. My guess is that they use some dedicated piece of hardware for instructions.

Comment: I guess all of these are possible. I think that the first case fit my program. I did some experiments with a loop that is unrolled in one version and not unrolled in another. The resulting larger binary code did not cause significant differences in runtime, increasing the number of repetitions only increased runtime linearly, as expected. While the size of the output of _cuobjdump --dump-sass_ is strange sometimes, this does not seem to impact runtime, which makes me wonder if "dead" code survives the optimizer sometimes.